# dpkg: error processing archive ( On installing Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, dpkg

This error occurred while installing nodejs
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMRiT.jpg]

I am trying to install nodejs but facing this error while installing.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1362727/666464 I had the same problem today.

Answer (score 27):

I got the same error,

```
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_18.15.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (18.15.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.15.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.15.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

but this is the exact error,

```
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
```

In my case removed the `libnode72` package by running the following command.

```
sudo apt remove libnode72

# If above does not work for you, run below commands

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode-dev
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode72:amd64
```

I think in your case you have to remove the `libnode-dev` package. Please try it by running the following command,

```
sudo apt remove libnode-dev
```

If this doesn't work for you or anyone, please add a comment.

Comment: remove 'libnode72' save my life... after: sudo apt --fix-broken install > sudo apt update > sudo apt remove nodejs > sudo apt remove nodejs-doc > curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash - > sudo apt-get install -y nodejs ... thanks bro !

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.12.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb

sudo apt -f install

sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Adapted from this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1362727/666464
I had the same problem today, and now it is solved.