# Error in after run command sudo apt upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu-22.04

Having Problem after running sudo apt upgrade

```
**Unpacking nodejs (16.19.0-deb-1nodesource1) over (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.19.0-deb-1nodes
ource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in pa
ckage libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.19.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
**
```

code should upgrade all the dependency

Comment: make sure you run `apt update` first. then can you try running `sudo apt install libnode` and then upgrade again and let us know if it works better?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnode

Comment: did you run `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: The following answer will help you to fix the problem, [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943902/6194097](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943902/6194097)